# After execute connection.commit(), why the others cursor.execute() not work correctly?

Tags: python, pymysql

I was using PyMysql lib to add some lines to my database, I got a very long list of SQL, maybe more than 150000 rows. So I thought to execute commit my every 5000 times, the code is here:

```
import pymysql

sql_list = ["sql1", "sql2", "sql3", ...]  # Very long list, more than 150000 rows
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port=3306,
    user="user",
    password="abc-123",
    database="test",
    charset="utf8"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

flag = 0  # flag, for the count
for sql in sql_list:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    flag += 1
    if flag > 5000:
        conn.commit()
        flag = 0
```

When I tried to run this script, I got some rows in my database, but not the full.
Then I have changed the code to this:

```
import pymysql

sql_list = ["sql1", "sql2", "sql3", ...]  # Very long list, more than 150000 rows
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port=3306,
    user="user",
    password="abc-123",
    database="test",
    charset="utf8"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# flag = 0  # flag, for the count
for sql in sql_list:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # flag += 1
    # if flag > 5000:
    #     conn.commit()
    #     flag = 0
conn.commit()
```

It works correctly! Why? Is my consideration redundant?
Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: Can you try autocommit:
`conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='user',
    passwd='passwd',
    db='db',
    autocommit=True
)`

Comment: @michael, wouldn't autocommit be too much overhead when executing 150000 sqls?

Comment: @michael No, no , no. Should **NOT** set the `autocommit` to `True`, except your SQLs is short enough, otherwise **execute** will trigger commit **every times**.  Just like this:
`cursor.execute("sql")
# conn.commit() will run after the execute.` This is a very consuming task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChowRex, you commit every 5000 rows. I guess that after the last commit there are additional sqls to execute and these are not commited. I think you need a final commit.

```
flag = 0  # flag, for the count
for sql in sql_list:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    flag += 1
    if flag > 5000:
        conn.commit()
        flag = 0
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You're meaning I lost the sql rows which was not long enough than 5000? For example, the total length is 19999, the 15000 rows was commit in the loop, but the last 4999 rows need one more commit to save data to database? Seems to clearly, thanks very much!